# Using same library with different version across virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am working on a project in python which have dependencies in multiple modules.

As an example say my **main module** uses another 2 modules namely **module_1** which needs library **lib_version_1.5** and **module_2** which uses the same **library_but_version_1.8** .

Both module_1 and module_2 is running fine, now I am creating another module combining these two.

So how can I use virtual environment so that I can combine these two with all required libraries (different versions) ? Is it possible to get different version of the same library installed within a project having different sub modules?

Comment: Only by namespacing the projects; packaging them in new top-level directories that are also packages. It'll depend on the projects if they are built for this (e.g. use `from . import name` relative imports).

Answer (score 5):

Note that the python namingspace is quite powerful. Hope this small Example will help you.

The basic theory is that add the same libs with different versions into the python's class path and make them be different names so that there will not be overriding.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'libs'))
```

The above code will insert the third-part libs which under the directory of 'libs' that under your project's base directory.

Suppose that I need pycrypto with version 2.4.1 and 2.6.1, use `pip install pycrypto==2.6.1 -t ./libs` and `ip install pycrypto==2.4.1 -t ./libs` to install the two versions into a sub-directory under your project. Modify their name after you have installed one, otherwise it will override the existed one.

Modify their names to Crypto241 and Crypto261 seprately.
[image: What my project looks like]

Let's say I will have two modules(`ModuleWIthCrypto241`, `ModuleWithCrypto261`) which will import pycrypto 2.4.1 and 2.6.1 seprately.

ModuleWithCrypto261 with code:

```
def getCryproVersion(baseDir):
    import os, sys
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(baseDir, 'libs'))
    import Crypto261
    return Crypto261.__version__
```

ModuleWIthCrypto241 with code:

```
def getCryproVersion(baseDir):
    import os, sys
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(baseDir, 'libs'))
    import Crypto241
    return Crypto241.__version__
```

Almost the same, just import the different version of pycrypto.

Then we have another script which try to get the two different version of pycrypto.`modulewithdiffversion.py`

What it looks like:

```
import os, sys

from com.x import ModuleWIthCrypto241
from com.x import ModuleWithCrypto261
if __name__ == '__main__':
    baseDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print ModuleWIthCrypto241.getCryproVersion(baseDir)
    print ModuleWithCrypto261.getCryproVersion(baseDir)
```

Execute the main method, it will print out the two versions of the pycrypto:

```
2.4.1
2.6.1
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Note that when you try this situation in real project, try the sys.path.isnert for only one time, otherwise you may insert the "libs" directory into the systems path for many times.