# How do you handle conflicting python library dependency versions

Tags: python, anaconda, dependencies, conda, conflicting-libraries

I want to run two different libraries that require different versions of the same dependency (for example if one library required pandas 0.25 and another library requires pandas 0.5).  I basically am running one library to prepare data, then run the other library to evaluate that data.  I noticed that this has been an issue with other projects where I need to make several conda environments to handle different libraries with different dependency versions, so I need to separate the tasks into different scripts and run everything separately.

My current solution is to just run the first library on the data, and then switch environments and run another script to run the second library.  This works, but it is a repetitive task, and preparing all the data then switching to evaluate it works but preparing all the data takes like 25gb and I have no interest in storing it after it is evaluated.

I was wondering how other people handle this problem.  Does everyone just create separate scripts and change environments to run them?  Do you guys change environments midway through your scripts in order to keep everything in the same script?  Is there a way I don't know to handle using two different libraries with different dependency versions?

Comment: I believe this should answer your question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208597/using-same-library-with-different-version-across-virtual-environment